# How to calculate total time by use of regex in C sharp?

Tags: c#

I want to calculate total "Elapsed time" for "GSA Search" by using regular expressions.

My log file is of format :

```
WX Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.com User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time: 975ms SaveSearchID:361
WX Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.com User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time: 875ms SaveSearchID:361
GSA Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.com User:gulanand appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:890ms SaveSearchID:361
GSA Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.com User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:887ms SaveSearchID:361
GSA Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.com User: gulanand appGUID: wx Elapsed Time: 875.5ms SaveSearchID:361
GSA Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.com User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:877.6ms SaveSearchID:361
```

My code :

```
 string searchKeyword = "WX GSA Search";
            string fileName = @"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\sample log.txt";
            string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

            List<string> results = new List<string>();

            foreach (string line in textLines)
            {
                if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
                {
                    results.Add(line);
                }
            }
            string x = string.Join(",", results);
            List<string> value = new List<string>();
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"Elapsed Time:\s*(?<value>\d+\.?\d*)\s*ms");
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(x);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var time = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                if (value.Contains(time)) value.Add(time);
            }
            int ElapsedTime = value.Count();
            Console.WriteLine(ElapsedTime);
            // keep screen from going away
            // when run from VS.NET
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq way :

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"Elapsed Time:\s*(?<value>\d+\.?\d*)\s*ms");
double totalTime = textLines.Where(line => line.Contains(searchKeyword))
                            .Select(line => regex.Match(line))
                            .Where(match => match.Captures.Count > 0)
                            .Sum(match => Double.Parse(match.Groups["value"].Value));
```

Non-Linq way :

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"Elapsed Time:\s*(?<value>\d+\.?\d*)\s*ms");
double totalTime = 0;
int count = 0;
foreach (string line in textLines)
{
    if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
    {
        Match match = regex.Match(line);
        if (match.Captures.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                count++;
                double time = Double.Parse(match.Groups["value"].Value);
                totalTime += time;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // not a number
            }
        }
    }
}

double average = totalTime/count;
```

Comment: What if i want to calculate the average ?

Comment: @DorgySharma - just replace `.Sum` with `.Average`.

Comment: here in code i don't see any .Sum function. To which variable it needs to be applied ? Thanks, actually my level is just beginner.

Comment: plus one more thing, in your code, it picks the elapsed time of all the searches. I need total Elapsed time only for "GSA Search".

Comment: thanks, but just one more thing, when i print this, it gives me all the numbers from GSA search, what if i want to perform Sum operation.

Comment: @DorgySharma - sum operation?

Comment: the sum is already stored in `totalTime` variable. so what else kind of sum are you looking for ?

Comment: yes u r right. Now in same if i want to calculate the average, how can i achieve in Non-LINQ. should i use : double Avg = totalTime/time.count;    but here error is thrown for "time"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25518/discussion-between-appdeveloper-and-dorgy-sharma)

Comment: thanks a lot. I learnt a new thing from you. Thanks for that.

Comment: @AppDeveloper Neat Linq way.

Answer (score 2):

You can get total time with LINQ without regular expressions (because your log file have consistent format). Here is a sample of calculating total, average and max time
(*DefaultIfEmpty* will return *0* if there is no log items for searched keyword):

```
string searchKeyword = "GSA Search";
var times = File.ReadAllLines("log.txt")
                .Where(l => l.Contains(searchKeyword))
                .Select(ParseElapsedTime)
                .DefaultIfEmpty() 
                .ToList();

 var averageTime = times.Average();   // 882,525
 var maxTime = times.Max();           // 890
 var totalTime = times.Sum();         // 3530,1
```

I suggest you to use separate method for parsing elapsed time from log line. That will make code more maintainable:

```
private static double ParseElapsedTime(string logLine)
{
    var startIndex = logLine.IndexOf("Elapsed Time:") + "Elapsed Time:".Length;
    var endIndex = logLine.IndexOf("ms", startIndex);
    var s = logLine.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex).Trim();
    return Double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
}
```

And you always can use regex to parse lines if [performance does not matters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/04/04/performance-comparison-regex-versus-string-operations.aspx) for you - just change method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have parsed the elapsed time per record in *ms* using your regex, you can convert the resulting string (e.g. `877.6`) to a floating-point value:

```
string time = "234.4";
float elapsed = Single.Parse(time, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Use `Single.Parse` only when you're sure the value is a valid floating-point value. Otherwise, you should use [`Single.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse.aspx) but it works a little bit differently.

You can use LINQ to easily sum the elapsed times from your list of `values`:

```
var values = new [] { "975", "875", "890", "887", "875.5", "877.6" };
float total = arr.Sum(v => Single.Parse(v, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in Vb (but can be easily translated to c#).  From your string above I got 5380.1 as a result.

```
Dim totaltime As Decimal = 0.0'choose your data type, I prefer decimal for accuracy
'This should get in between "Time:" and "ms" 
Dim getTimesRgx As New Regex("(?<=Time:)(.*?)(?=ms)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim Times As MatchCollection = getTimesRgx.Matches(YourFileAsString)
If Times.Count > 0 Then
   For Each time As Match In Times
      totaltime = totaltime + Decimal.parse(time.value)
   Next
End If
```